# Send emails : Cron job

Tags: cron

in my project, i need to send emails to the registered members of the site once every month. For this, i have setup a cron job on cpanel and it is working fine.

Whats my doubt is that, tomorrow the number of users in the site will increase and there would be thousands of users. Then does the cron job work as usual ?

I want to know, whether the cron can handle the task of sending emails to thousands of users at a time.

Please help.

Comment: This question should be on serverfault.com -- it is not programming related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful. Most servers are set to only send a set amount of emails at a time, and the results of trying to send more than this at once can be catastrophic (speaking from experience).

I would pause the send for now, and speak to your hosting company to find out the best way to proceed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your suggestion. For now, i have around 100 users, for whom, sending emails wont be a problem according to me. Lets see how far the cron is able to handle it.